# Accept cookies only from certain sites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, privacy, blocking, cookies

I've recently discovered the add-on I used to use in Firefox to only accept cookies from certain sites ("Cookie Monster") is no longer available.

I've seen there are still many other addons in order to delete cookies, disable cookies, etc. But I've found none which allow me to what I was doing until now: Accept cookies from a "white list" of sites and reject cookies from any other.

This was one of my most beloved Firefox features, anyone knows any way to achieve this behaviour with any other addon/settings configuration?

20171224 EDIT:

I accepted the answer prior to update (as I've done today) to Firefox 57.

I've discovered (I hope I'm wrong) that Firefox is forcing me to activate "private browsing mode" in order to be able to block cookies by default.

Someone could think "Well, if you browse privately, what's the problem?".

The problem is that I don't want Firefox to forget what windows I had open; I want hem to be restored in the next session.

I don't want Firefox to force me to go to Edit -> Settings -> Privacy & Security, scroll to Exceptions, etc. Just to block or unblock a certain site, maybe for just some minutes. And also, I don't want to be asked to write down the URL; I want at least a button like "Block this site cookies" (Is it so difficult?)

I don't want to mix cookies management with private browsing; I want to be able to NOT USE PRIVATE BROWSING and yet be able to decide which sites I want to let use cookies and which not.

I'm deeply disappointed with Mozilla.

I've been always a proud user of Mozilla products, but this issue force me to stop using Firefox since I don't want to decide between browsing in complete private mode or let every site use its cookies by default.

I won't ask again for an addon like "Cookie Monster" since I think it's a limitation related to the API, but if anyone has any other solution, please let me know it; still don't know what browser to use instead of Firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without the needing to install add-ons.

Go to: about:preferences > Privacy > History > Use custom setting for history.

Here, you can set blacklists and whitelists for accepting cookies.

Comment: I guess I got too used to Cookie Monster (still I'll miss it; it was very cozy). You are right. Thanks. By the way: Any way of getting it on Firefox for Android?

Comment: @AlbertoMartín You can disable cookies on Android, but I'm not sure how to whitelist webpages. Please post another question, which should give you more answers.